# OpenCL error when GPU rendering in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, error, opencl, gpu

When I try to render using my AMD 5600XT in Cycles, I get a error that says

> OpenCL error (-52): CL_INVALID_KERNEL_ARGS in clEnqueueNDRangeKernel

This happens in any scene, even a brand new one after opening Blender. I have updated all of my drivers and restarted my computer multiple times. This happens on Blender 2.9x, I haven't tried any Blender 2.8x versions.

Answer (score 0):

had exactly the same problem when I was trying to view (not even render) a scene with volumetrics in it.

My scene had: a sky environment texture and a default cube with principle volume shader puggled into volume output. Here's what worked for me:-

1. In anything but render view, switch to render with CPU.
2. Go into render view
3. Then in render view swithc to render with GPU.

I have no idea why this worked for me or if it will do you or anyone else any good. All I can say is I think the problem is with OpenCL, kinda wish I'd brought an Nvidia GPU now.